# No rule to make target when running Build in Docker Container in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, docker, docker-machine, docker-container

I have set up a Docker Machine and am able to connect to it with Eclipse.
I can configure a container and run it. No problems. However when i try to build my application in the Docker Container it is giving me a "No rule to make target" error. 
When I build my application outside of the Docker Container it builds like expected.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Ive narrowed down the problem. When i pass "ls" as build command I see that there is no makefile. Somehow Eclipse does not pass the files into the docker container. Do I need to set this up mannualy?

Comment: Running an involved `make` outside of Docker space, then running `docker build` to package the result into an image, is pretty routine.  Is there a more specific problem you're having?  Can you include a [mcve] of your issue, including relevant fragments of the Dockerfile and the Makefile?

Comment: Added information. Does this help?